# buttons are being cut off of the page

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two sets of controls within a row.  They are both in their respective stack panels.  The first is aligned to the left and the second is aligned to the right.  It looks good, except that the controls on the right are cut off by the application window.  I can stretch out the window with my mouse and it looks fine, but it would be better if the buttons would just push in as the application window collapses.

Here is the xaml:

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="5">
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"                  
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Label Content="Instant Message Text"                   
                   Margin="5"></Label>
                <TextBox x:Name="txt_Message"                            
                         Width="400"></TextBox>
                <Button Name="btn_instantMessage"                        
                    Content="Send Message"></Button>
                <Label Content="Send To All Zones"></Label>
                <CheckBox Name="chk_sentMessageToAllZones"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"></CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <Button Content="Stop All Ads"
                        Margin="5"
                        Name="btn_stop"></Button>
                <Button Content="Play All Ads"
                        Margin="5"
                        Name="btn_play"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Here is a screen shot of the damage.  You can see how the button "Play All Ads" is getting cut off.
[image]

Comment: What is the size of the initial <Grid> element? You can use a tool like Snoop to investigate. I would guess that something is preventing it from sizing larger.

Comment: "push in" how? You have a TextBox with a Width of 400 so if the window's get smaller there is no where for your StackPanel to be "pushed in", is it? Or where and how do you expect it to appear?

Comment: I set the width of the window to 1000 pixels.  It doesn't matter if I set it to 1200 pixels though, the appearance of the screen shot does not change.

Comment: I hacked this by setting a weird right margin, but, it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You should set SizeToContent property on your window/UC.

```
SizeToContent="Width"
```